# Building a Chrome extension for the Chrome Web Store, want to open in a new tab

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Building a Chrome extension for the Chrome Web Store, want to open in a new tab, can't work it out. This is [my extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/our-blinds/iflmndgbmlcjnmcgbiciacmlknhmdpei) and as you can see, it is opening the window within the extension.   I want it to be able to open either a new tab and go straight to the webpage, or load my website from whatever page they are on.

The JSON I wrote:

```
    {
"name": "Our Blinds",
"version": "0.2",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "This app will link to the Our Blinds website, where you can buy made to measure window blinds",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "128.png",
    "default_title": "made to measure window blinds",
    "default_popup": "www.ourblinds.co.uk"
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
"icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
}
}
```

What do I need to change to make it open in a new tab? I thought by having the web address as a default popup, it should open in a new or the same tab.

For example, [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vs-launcher/cmhicdplfejcchpmimlnohfadpimciaa) does what I want my extension to do, but obviously to my own website and not theirs. I want people to be able to add the extension, and in 1 click appear on my website www.ourblinds.co.uk.

Comment: I've changed it to           {  
   "name":"Our Blinds",
   "version":"1.3",
   "manifest_version":2,
   "description":"This extension will link to the Our Blinds website, where you can buy made to measure window blinds",
   "browser_action":{  
      "default_icon":"128.png",
      "default_title":"made to measure window blinds",
      "default_popup":"www.ourblinds.co.uk/",
      "permissions":"new tab"
   },
   "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'"
} and still doesn't work, it's now not loading the website.

Comment: I've removed it because it wasn't working. Got it working as an app... https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/our-blinds/ljacgjpcbnnclpgeddpmcbdacpmecffh  want an extension to do exactly the same as the app please help.

Answer (score 2):

`"default_popup"` key in manifest can only point to a local html file that contains the popup (a very small window that appears after the toolbar icon is clicked). You don't need it. Use a [background (event) page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) script with a [click listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) instead that [opens a new tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create):

- manifest.json, relevant parts:

  ```
      "browser_action": {
          "default_icon": "128.png",
          "default_title": "made to measure window blinds",
      },
      "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"],
          "persistent": false
      },
  ```
- background.js:

  ```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.create({
          url: 'http://exampe.com',
          active: true,
      });
  });
  ```

P.S. Your 128px icon now won't look sharp because it's automatically stretched to the correct size. Consider making a properly scaled icons of 16x16, 19x19, 32x32, 38x38 sizes used by Chrome and declare them the same way (`"16": "16.png"` and so on).